# Show an image from a URL in WinForms PictureBox

Tags: winforms

Hi I have a WinForms project targetting .net core. I am trying to load an image from a URL, but all I am getting is this:

[image: screenshot]

Inside a UserControl I have added a PictureBox (pic1) and a Button.

Added the following as an example to the click event of the button:

```
pic1.LoadAsync("https://images.pexels.com/photos/4815143/pexels-photo-4815143.jpeg");
```

also

```
pic1.ImageLocation = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4815143/pexels-photo-4815143.jpeg";
```

Have tried with different URLs

Any ideas what is wrong?

**Edit**
I've tried an alternative option, something seems to be getting stuck on DownloadData

```
 using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
 {
 byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData("https://images.pexels.com/photos/4815143/pexels-photo-4815143.jpg");


    using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem))
        {
        
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: The code works as expected. Maybe you haven't assigned the event handler to the event. Maybe you pic1 is not the Control that you are looking for.

Comment: Nope, it's definitly referencing the right control. Before I click the button, it is an empty grey box. After clicking it, it comes up with that placeholder image.

Comment: Works fine.  The placeholder is shown while the download is in progress.  Something is interfering with that download on your machine, not ours.

Comment: Any ideas on where to check what the interference is? I've tried turning off Windows firewall, didn't help

Comment: Turning off the Firewall is not useful. Can you ping `images.pexels.com`? Some weird DNS settings? Local policies in place that ban specific sites? Maybe in your workplace? -- What Windows System is this code tested on?